# How to split Google Sheet across tabs whilst retaining references

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, cross-reference

I have a Google Sheet which contains two 'tables' of information one holding Common data on the left, and one holding specific data on the right. (In my real life scenario have about 10 other tables matching the schema of the right-hand table) [See example on my Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGZlpDaLmeWupOq7HRq-w_Cgsdfvf9H2LC7eAzyNic4/edit?usp=sharing)

The table on the right has a column (G3:G4) which uses a formula (`=($B$6/100*F3)*1000`) that derives values from:

- a cell (`B6`) in the 'common' table, and
- a cell in the right table.

I would like to split this sheet within the workbook so we have one 'table' per tab. I would have one tab for the Common table and other tabs for each of the remaining specific tables.

When I do the split, the formula breaks and I get Reference does not exist.

How do I preserve the reference in the formula whilst splitting a Google sheet across multiple tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Dmitry](https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01273da44cade36a1d)

- In the Google Sheeet > `Astrid` Tab
- Rename `Astrid` tab to `Common` (to convey that it will hold the common table)
- Mentally note and watch the values that are about to be changed.
- Go to Edit > Find and replace... and set:

  - Find: `$B$6`
  - Replace with: `Common!$B$6`
  - *Also search within forumlas*: ticked
- Click **Replace All**
- Assert that the values have remained the same
- Assert that no reference errors have been created.
- Create new empty tab for Astrid Table, called `Astrid`
- In `Common` tab select the Astrid table
- `Copy` (CTRL+C or Apple + C)
- In `Astrid` tab, put cursor in cell A1
- `Paste` (CTRL+V or Apple + V)

This technique keeps the reference to the common table that stayed put whilst also keeping the reference to the Specific table that has moved.

Other techniques, such as duplicating tabs and pruning, have issues that can waste a user's time.